# Use additional IP in a KVM vps

Tags: virtualization, centos7, ip, kvm-virtualization

How can I use an IP in a KVM vps when my provider states "The additional IPs we provide are forwarded. It means they have to be forwarded through the main IP of the server"

I have a bridge created on server and assigned to my KVM vps .

Comment: Any link from the provider about this?

Comment: Really, I can think about multiple ways this could be possibly done (from simple routing, to, let's be imaginative, proxy arp or IPVTAP interfaces), but a link from the provider would clarify it. If you could add that in the question (a link rather than a quote which went out of context) a correct guess could probably be done.